# Column of a selected row in Listview in Selectionchanged event handler

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

this is very easy question but all web solution i found didn't work

is it good to use selection changed event i want event to fire only when i mouse click on row, otherwise i can scroll through all list ?

Answer (score 0):

I never tested but i think you can use a simple RelayCommand with the event "Click" to manage this.